# 500 Internal Server error with csv reader script

Tags: php

I am  working on php script which downloads and reads csv file and imports things to database. But I have a problem: when this script is working for a long time, I will get Error 500 - Internal Server Error. I don't know why, but server have set execution time on 90 sec, but my script is working longer time (about 6 minutes) and then I get this error.

When I got execution time error it's ok, because I can catch it with register_shutdown_function() and make another instance with cUrl, but this error is uncatchable for me.

Have anyone any clue how to catch it or make execution time error working ?

I tried set_time_limit(), but it's not working too, because server is in safe mode. And it's web hosting, so I can't change php.ini or something like this.

Thanks for any answer

Comment: In general for HTTP 500 errors first thing to do is check the web server logs, they normally contain more detailed info.

Comment: I can't check webserver log, it's hosting. But I tried it on my xampp server and it works ok, without error.